# How to move on after login

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-api

I'm pretty new to this and I'm hoping anyone could share some ideas.

I've set up login using google's api. The idea now is to move on and use the next view controller (or the next stage in the app)

two things I'd like to acoomplish are:

1. register some of the user's details on my own server (if permitted by Google
2. Move on to a menu - but only once the user is logged in.

What are some ways to do that ?

Comment: If you want to move to the next `UIViewController`, you could start by pushing the next ViewController onto the `UINavigationController`. Or you could pop the controller off without animating, once you've confirmed that a user has logged in successfully.

Comment: sounds tough. where do i start ?

Comment: you do a search on how to segue between view controllers, you try it, and if something doesn't work you come back here and post the code and we can help out :)